# Python: How to sort list of dictionaries by value and index

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of a dictionary of data that is in order in some places and out of order in others:

Eg:

```
data = [{"text":'a', "value":1},
        {"text":'b', "value":1},
        {"text":'j', "value":2},
        {"text":'k', "value":50},
        {"text":'b', "value":50},
        {"text":'y', "value":52},
        {"text":'x', "value":2},
        {"text":'k', "value":3},
        {"text":'m', "value":3}]
```

I want to sort them as:

```
 o = [{"text":'a', "value":1},
      {"text":'b', "value":1},
      {"text":'j', "value":2},
      {"text":'x', "value":2},
      {"text":'k', "value":3},
      {"text":'m', "value":3},
      {"text":'k', "value":50},
      {"text":'b', "value":50},
      {"text":'y', "value":52}]
```

wherein my sorting is some combination of the index of the item and the 2nd value, I was thinking sort with:

```
key=[(2nd value)<<len(closest power of 2 to len(index)) + index]
```

I can sort by the list of dicts by the 2nd value with:

```
data.sort(key= lambda x:x['value'])
```

How do I also add the index of the dictionary?

And is there a better sorting key I could use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that you're looking for the `text` field as a secondary sort key.  The easiest way is to simply use a tuple for your keys, in priority order:

```
sorted(data, key=lambda x: (x['value'], x['text']) )
```

Does that yield what you need?  Output:

```
[{'text': 'a', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'b', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'j', 'value': 2}, {'text': 'x', 'value': 2}, {'text': 'k', 'value': 3}, {'text': 'm', 'value': 3}, {'text': 'b', 'value': 50}, {'text': 'k', 'value': 50}, {'text': 'y', 'value': 52}]
```

The values (k, 50) and (b, 50) are now in the other order; I'm hopeful that I read your mind correctly.

---

**UPDATE per OP clarification**

I checked the docs.  Python's `sort` method is *stable*, so you don't need the second sort key at all: in case of a tie, `sort` will maintain the original ordering:

```
>>> data.sort(key= lambda x:x['value'])
>>> data
[{'text': 'a', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'b', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'j', 'value': 2}, {'text': 'x', 'value': 2}, {'text': 'k', 'value': 3}, {'text': 'm', 'value': 3}, {'text': 'k', 'value': 50}, {'text': 'b', 'value': 50}, {'text': 'y', 'value': 52}]
```

... and this is what you requested.

Comment: I'm not looking for the text field as the secondary sort key, I'm looking for the list index of the item in the list to be the secondary sort key

Comment: Ah.  In that case, all you need is any *stable* sort.  Check the documentation(s) to see which will preserve the original order, in case of a tie.  I believe that `sorted` already does this.

Answer (score 3):

Use `enumerate` to get the index and use that to sort

```
>>> res = [d for i,d in sorted(enumerate(data), key=lambda i_d: (i_d[1]['value'], i_d[0]))]
>>> pprint(res)
[{'text': 'a', 'value': 1},
 {'text': 'b', 'value': 1},
 {'text': 'j', 'value': 2},
 {'text': 'x', 'value': 2},
 {'text': 'k', 'value': 3},
 {'text': 'm', 'value': 3},
 {'text': 'k', 'value': 50},
 {'text': 'b', 'value': 50},
 {'text': 'y', 'value': 52}]
```

To sort it in-place, you can try using `itertools.count`

```
>>> from itertools import count
>>> cnt=count()
>>> data.sort(key=lambda d: (d['value'], next(cnt)))
>>> pprint(data)
[{'text': 'a', 'value': 1},
 {'text': 'b', 'value': 1},
 {'text': 'j', 'value': 2},
 {'text': 'x', 'value': 2},
 {'text': 'k', 'value': 3},
 {'text': 'm', 'value': 3},
 {'text': 'k', 'value': 50},
 {'text': 'b', 'value': 50},
 {'text': 'y', 'value': 52}]
>>>
```

Comment: This works. Is there any way to do it with sort instead of sorted (don't want to use more memory).

Comment: @azazelspeaks. Updated the answer

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this:

```
sorted(data, key=lambda x: x['value'])
```

Comment: That is literally what I've said I've tried. Sort & sorted both sort. I'm looking to sort by two keys.