# is sorting of list of dictionaries by a nested key

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of dictionaries in Python, each containing information about a person. Each dictionary has keys like 'name', 'age', and 'address'. Within the list, I want to sort the dictionaries based on the 'age' key in ascending order. However, 'age' is a nested key within each dictionary. How can I achieve this sorting using Python?

Example Data:

```
 people = [     {'name': 'Alice', 'info': {'age': 30, 'address': '123 Main St'}},
 {'name': 'Bob', 'info': {'age': 25, 'address': '456 Elm St'}},
  {'name': 'Charlie', 'info': {'age': 35, 'address': '789 Oak St'}},
   # ... more dictionaries
   ]
```

Need answer in the Python 3

Comment: You forgot to post your attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: How to sort list of dictionaries by value and index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51776799/python-how-to-sort-list-of-dictionaries-by-value-and-index) Recognize that in your lambda function, you can drill into your list member dictionary as deeply as you like.

Comment: `people.sort(key=lambda row: row["info"]["age"])`

Answer (score 0):

Using your dictionary,

```
print(people[0]['info']['age'])
```

Will print the value of age for the first person.
So you will have to iterate through the nested dictionary.
Let's dive into this:

`people[0]` is the index of each row in people, here the first.

`['info']` is the nested dictionary where the age and the address is stored.

`['age']` is the value of the age key.

So if you loop inside `people`, then loop inside the nested `info` dictionary, looking for the key `age`, you will print the value of age for each person.

I made a working example but you will need to replace the INT type to STRING for age:

```
for person in people:
    for age in person['info']['age']:
        print(age)
```